# Web RAD tool suggestion?

Tags: ajax, visual-programming

I'm currently looking for good (and free if possible) Web RAD (Rapid Application Development) tool or Visual Ajax IDE, something like [Morfik](http://www.morfik.com) or [Delphi for PHP](http://www.codegear.com/products/delphi/php) with more usual deployment method (both create standalone application or web server modules). What i mean was IDE that support drag-n-drop component for building web application and the result was standard .(x)html & .js (and maybe .php) files so i can upload it to my favorite web host right away.

I already inspecting [VisualWebGui](http://www.visualwebgui.com/), [Visual Ajax Studio](http://www.wavemaker.com/product/), [Visual Ajax Builder](http://www.backbase.com/products/visual-ajax-builder/) but all have same method as above for deployment (some using Java platform).

I then take a look [Sigma Visual](http://www.sigmawidgets.com/products/sigma_visual/), checked the demo, but it was too slow...

Maybe better to wait Delphi for PHP with [EXTJS](http://extjs.com/) as their GUI package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you dont just use Visual Studio Web Developer ?
or [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org)

Comment: as far as i know, eclipse was multi-programming language IDE, does it support visual (drag-n-drop component)? And Visual Studio Web Developer, i can't found an offline installer for the free version (i only get web installer which was pain)

Comment: eclipse does support visual and you can find always visual studio in rapidsahre

Comment: If you want a visual, drag and drop IDE that is open source, try [Wavemaker](http://www.wavemaker.com/)

Answer (score 3):

I have found this : [VisualJS.NET](http://visualjs.net) (very interesting and promising)

Answer (score 1):

Have a good look at ChrisSoftEng.co.uk. Quite a lot of free stuff - RAD for the Web - Delphi PHP, Delphi VCL for Web, GO-Global for Windows on EC2. And Xajax and SVG as well as Silverlight and Java Web Start. This is a site for co-working projects without fees.

Answer (score 0):

I use [AlphaFive](http://www.alphafive.com), check their website for support and services.